# Object doesn't support property or method 'prepend'

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Estou tentando tornar minha aplicação WEB compatível com o Navegador Edge. Porém eu recebo a mensagem "Object doesn't support property or method 'prepend'" no console quanto eu tento executar o seguinte código:

```
    var li = document.createElement("li");
 ...
    var list = document.getElementById("history");
    if (this.stackHistory.size() === 0) {
        list.innerHTML = "";
        list.appendChild(li);
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById("historyorder").value === "last")
           list.prepend(li); //ERROR AQUI
        else
           list.appendChild(li);
}
```

Tal código funcionou no Google Chrome e Firefox

Comment: `prepend` não é suportado nem no IE nem no Edge. [Confirme na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend)

Comment: Explique mais @dvd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O método [`prepend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) que indicou não é suportado no navegador Edge nem no IE.

[Isso é algo que consegue confirmar na parte de compatibilidade da documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend#Browser_compatibility)

No entanto pode utilizar o *polyfill* que a própria documentação indica:

```
(function (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('prepend')) {
      return;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(item, 'prepend', {
      configurable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      writable: true,
      value: function prepend() {
        var argArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
          docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

        argArr.forEach(function (argItem) {
          var isNode = argItem instanceof Node;
          docFrag.appendChild(isNode ? argItem : document.createTextNode(String(argItem)));
        });

        this.insertBefore(docFrag, this.firstChild);
      }
    });
  });
})([Element.prototype, Document.prototype, DocumentFragment.prototype]);
```

[Link para este polyfill no github](https://github.com/jserz/js_piece/blob/master/DOM/ParentNode/prepend()/prepend().md)

O *polyfill* acima indicado é o código que irá adicionar "ao navegador" ao função `prepend` caso ele não a suporte. Por este motivo terá de ser executado antes do código que utiliza o `prepend`.

Comment: @dvd O *polyfill* não é para adicionar um elemento é para adicionar a função `prepend` "ao navegador" fazendo com que `prepend` passe a funcionar na mesma no IE e no Edge. Note que eu não "inventei" este código. Ele está no fim da pagina de documentação no MDN linkada na minha resposta. Simplesmente coloquei aqui para acrescentar mais conteúdo relevante à resposta.

Comment: @dvd A vantagem de usar polyfill é que neste caso pode utilizar código JS puro e funcionar em todos os browsers, mesmo sendo uma função recente como o `prepend`. A única particularidade é que tem de chamar este código de polyfill uma vez no inicio de carregamento da página, o que pode até ser num arquivo incluído só com polyfills por exemplo. Logo parece na verdade pior do que é